# The javascript code from server side is not working in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am developing an Asp.net application when i call javascript function from codebehind i found that for example:

1. click event not fired
2. i have a javascript function that fill the dropdown list  with items using ajax but when page loaded i found dropdown list empty

i am using RegisterClientScriptBlock to execute the javascript code

so is there any solution for these problems?

code snippet:

code behind:

```
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ClientBlock",   javacode.ToString());
```

this what in javacode variable :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
     function ExecuteScript()
     {
    $("#divGender input").click();
     GetDMspecifyList(5); 
    $("cp1_drpDMSpecify").removeAttr('disabled'); 
    $("cp1_drpDMSpecify option:selected").val(4);
    $("#divFamily input").click();
     }
    </script>
     // -->
```

this the function used to fill dropdown list but it is not working

```
    function GetDMspecifyList(DMID) {
    $("#DMLoader").show();
    $.getJSON('FillDropDownLists.aspx?DMTypeID=' + DMID, function (types) {
    $.each(types, function () {
        $("#cp1_drpDMSpecify").append($("<option></option>").val(this['DMTypeCode']).html(this['DMTypeName']));
    });
    $("#DMLoader").hide();
    $("#DMSpecify_span").show();
    $("#cp1_hdDMType").val($("#cp1_drpDMSpecify").val());
    $("#cp1_drpDMSpecify").removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

}

Comment: try using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

Comment: Can you share your code? What you tried so far?

Comment: i added the code in the topic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the function "ExecuteScript()" is lacking it's closing curly brace "}".

Also, is the ExecuteScript() function called anywhere?

**EDIT**

You could try something similar to the code below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
     function ExecuteScript() {
         $("#divGender input").click();

         GetDMspecifyList(5, function() {
             $("cp1_drpDMSpecify").removeAttr('disabled');
             $("cp1_drpDMSpecify option:selected").val(4);
             $("#divFamily input").click();
         });
     }

     function GetDMspecifyList(DMID, callback) {
         $("#DMLoader").show();
         $.getJSON('FillDropDownLists.aspx?DMTypeID=' + DMID, function (types) {
             $.each(types, function () {
                 $("#cp1_drpDMSpecify").append($("<option></option>").val(this['DMTypeCode']).html(this['DMTypeName']));
             });
             $("#DMLoader").hide();
             $("#DMSpecify_span").show();
             $("#cp1_hdDMType").val($("#cp1_drpDMSpecify").val());
             $("#cp1_drpDMSpecify").removeAttr('disabled');

             callback();
         });
     }


     $(function() { ExecuteScript(); });
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: yeah the curly bracket there in my code :) sorry for missed it here  and No its Called only once

Comment: My guess, looking at the current code, you only add the ExecuteScipt function, but are not executing. Try adding ExecuteScript(); at the end of the "javacode" variable content.

Comment: Or even better (since you are using jQuery) : $(function() { ExecuteScript(); }); This will execute the function when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: when i called only the function by name nothing happened but with $(function() { ExecuteScript(); }); it works, but for only the the line inside that function this on-->   GetDMspecifyList(5);  "its an ajax request" but not working with click event actually its changed the value for the control  i mean if the value is "1" i found it "2" something like that i don't know why !!!!

Comment: I believe the fact that you are getting strange behaviour is because of the ajax call. You are trying to set the value on "cp1_drpDMSpecify" while making the ajax call to "FillDropDownLists.aspx". Try adding a callback function to "GetDMspecifyList" and execute that when your ajax call returns.

Comment: how do you mean to set the value for cp1_drpDMSpecify after ajax call?? because i did that and the value doesn't set only the dropdown filled with items !!!

Comment: mmm the same problem doesn't not selected the value for the list :S

Comment: Aah, afaik $("cp1_drpDMSpecify option:selected").val(4); should be : $("cp1_drpDMSpecify").val(4);

Comment: for the ajax one now its ok :), the other problem it when i fire the click event the value set to 0 not to the correct one,so i need to fire click event to make changes in other field depends on selected value so how to handle that, really i appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: i wan only  to mention that i solved by calling the function for click event not firing the event itself